# Why is my custom current scheduler replaced by the default one when I use ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a custom `TaskScheduler` which is supposed to execute given tasks on the same thread. This task scheduler is used with a custom task factory. This task factory executes an async method `ReadFileAsync` which calls another async method `ReadToEndAsync` of `StreamReader`.

I've noticed that after using `ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`, the current task scheduler is reverted back to the default one, `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`. If I remove `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the custom task scheduler `SameThreadTaskScheduler` is kept. Why? Is there any way to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` with the same custom scheduler after its execution?

I've tried multiple things, but the result is the same:

- Change the enum flags of the custom `TaskFactory`
- Using a custom synchronization context that `Posts` the callback synchronously instead of the thread pool
- Change and revert the synchronization inside the task function executed on the task factory
- Change and revert the synchronization outside of the task function executed on the task factory

```
public static class Program
{
    private static readonly string DesktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

    public static void Main()
    {
        _ = AsyncHelper.RunSynchronously(ReadFileAsync);
    }

    private static async Task<string> ReadFileAsync()
    {
        // Prints "SameThreadTaskScheduler"
        Console.WriteLine(TaskScheduler.Current.GetType().Name);

        using var fs = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(DesktopPath, "hello.txt"));
        var content = await fs.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // <-------- HERE

        // With ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false), prints "ThreadPoolTaskScheduler"
        // With ReadToEndAsync() only, prints "SameThreadTaskScheduler"
        Console.WriteLine(TaskScheduler.Current.GetType().Name);

        return content;
    }
}

public static class AsyncHelper
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory SameThreadTaskFactory = new TaskFactory(
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None,
        new SameThreadTaskScheduler());

    public static TResult RunSynchronously<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
    {
        var oldContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        try
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
            return SameThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(func).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        finally
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(oldContext);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class SameThreadTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => 1;

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        this.TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        this.TryExecuteTask(task);
        return true;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Task>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help a lot to know *why* you're calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` if you care about keeping custom state consistent.

Comment: It seems that you are frustrated because the `ConfigureAwait(false)` does exactly what is supposed to do. Which is kinda strange. It's like asking why the `+` operator performs addition, and how you could stop it from performing addition. Well, OK. If you don't like that the `ConfigureAwait(false)` configures the `await` so that it doesn't capture the current context or scheduler, what would you like it to do? Would you like it to be a no-op?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your custom scheduler? Can it be accomplished with `AsyncLocal<T>` instead? Are you blocking on asynchronous code?

Comment: I was trying to understand why the current custom task scheduler changes after calling async with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. With your comments and answers, I get it now!

Comment: My story is that I'm working on a desktop .NET 4.5 application that uses a custom task scheduler to limit the number of thread that can be spawned. While trying to migrate it to .NET Core 3.1, I had to replace use of `HttpWebRequest`with `HttpClient`.

At first, I noticed that it was using the custom thread-limiter task scheduler, resulting in thread starvation. That's why I'm trying to ensure that `HttpClient` async methods and callbacks were executed on the same thread with another task scheduler.

Comment: The `TaskScheduler`s are useless regarding asynchronous operations. A `TaskScheduler` specifies where to run the delegate of a delegate-based task. But asynchronous methods create promise-style tasks, not delegate-based tasks. A promise-style task cannot be scheduled because it is already started upon creation, and typically [it's not running on a thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). For limiting the concurrency of async operations you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `continueOnCapturedContext` in `ConfigureAwait(bool continueOnCapturedContext)` has the following meaning: If `true` is specified, this means that the continuation should be marshaled back to the original context captured. If `false` is specified, the continuation may run on an arbitrary context.

The synchronization context is an abstraction for scheduling. A `TaskScheduler` is a concrete implementation. So by specifying `ConfigureAwait(false)`, you state that any TaskScheduler can be used. If you want to use your special TaskScheduler, than use `ConfigureAwait(true)`.

For more information on this topic, take a look at [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).